# Display only one column in combo box from List collection Items

Tags: c#, .net

```
portfolioHeaders = PortfolioService.GetPortfolioHeadersByQuery();

List<PortfolioHeaders> list = new List<PortfolioHeaders>;
list.AddRange(portfolioHeaders);
```

The above is the code.

the output of it will be ID, Name, Type and Modified Date.

when i use the list to Grid Datasource i could see all the records coming out perfectly.

Now My question is

I jUst want only the Name to be displayed in the ComboBox and ignoring the other things.

can anyone suggest me a way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DisplayMember attribute of your binding:

```
List<MyHeaders> headers = new List<MyHeaders>();
headers.Add( new MyHeaders{ID=10, Name="Yo"} );
headers.Add( new MyHeaders{ID=2, Name="OY"} );
headers.Add( new MyHeaders{ID=3, Name="Pickles"} );
headers.Add( new MyHeaders{ID=4, Name="Florky"} );

this.comboBox1.DataSource = headers;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Answer (score 3):

How about,

```
var names = list.Select( p => p.Name);
comboBox1.DataSource = names;
comboBox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set "DisplayMember" property of the ComboBox to "Name", and also "ValueMember" to "Name" (if you want to refer to the value).

Answer (score 0):

The PortfolioHeaders class, override the toString function.  Then add your list of items to the combo box.  With whatever the overridden tostring function returns is what will be displayed in the combo box.